# /etc files keep reverting after changes

Tags: configuration, etc

My problem is when I configure a file in `/etc`, for instance, I made changes , with sudo,in

> /etc/default/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon

well, after restarting I noticed the changes I made are not applied and I found a new file

> /etc/default/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon~

beside my original file, and that file with the tilde at the end contains the initial configuration which is apparently applied instead of my changed file. This problem exists for every change I madke in `/etc` folder.

Comment: How did you edit the file? What program did you use?

Comment: sudo gedit /path/to/file

Comment: I still supect some kind of user error :-) (some programs create a ~ file as safeguard, to keep the last version). For a diagnosis: try it once more, then (before rebooting) look at the output of `ls -l /etc/default/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon` (the date/time should be new) and `cat /etc/default/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to change isn't actually the configuration.  You're making edits to a pseudo file (a representation of the service).  The service only outputs there.

To make changes to IPSEC edit this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/ipsec.conf
```

or this file for L2TP:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf
```

Use this site for config reference:

http://blog.riobard.com/2010/04/30/l2tp-over-ipsec-ubuntu/

Comment: thank you, for the `l2tp-ipsec-vpn-daemon` file, I just want to disable the daemon at startup; another file for example `/etc/default/cups` I want to disable lp driver.